# Binding table names to SQL query using JDBI

Tags: mysql, jdbi

I am issuing a simple mysql select query using JDBI. In that if I try to bind the table name, I am getting wrong SQL syntax error.

Code snippet:

```
@SqlQuery("select * from <table> where rowid=:rowid")
@SingleValueResult
@Mapper(ContentRecordMapper.class)
public abstract Optional<Document> getRecord(@Define("table") String table, @Bind("rowid") String rowid);
```

If I execute this, I am getting

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<table> where rowid='row1'' at line 1 [statement:"select * from <table> where rowid=:rowid", located:"select * from <table> where rowid=:rowid", rewritten:"/* ContentDAO.getRecord */ select * from <table> where rowid=?", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{rowid:'row1'}, finder:[]}]
```

If I hard code the table name, I am getting proper results. Kindly help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should annotate with @UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator. It was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790529/dynamic-order-in-jdbi-sql-object-queries).