# How to input list of string to a sql using BindBeans

Tags: java, sql, dropwizard, jdbi

For some reason i can not use BindIn but have to use BindBeans to pass in a list of string values for in clause. I have below, but seems can not pass the Types as i wanted. Any advise please?

```
*MyFilter {
private final String Types; 
private final Timestamp Date;
 public MyFilter (){
    this.Types = "A','B"
    THIS.Date = now();
 }

}
@SqlQuery("select * from table where type in (:Types) and date = :Date  ")
public abstract List<xx> get(@BindBean MyFilter filter);*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some dynamic part(s) of SQL you can use stringtemplates.

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
public abstract class MyDAO {

    @SqlQuery("select * from table where type in (<types>) and date = :Date  ")
    public abstract List<xx> get(@Define("types") String types);

....
```

You will need to add this dependency:

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
       <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
       <version>3.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

In my case, it was very useful for dynamic sorting. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with @BindIn:

```
@SqlQuery("select * from table where type in (<types>) and date = :Date")
public abstract List<xx> get(@BindIn List<String> filter);
```

For `@BindIn` to work, you will also need to add `@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator` to your access class. JDBI needs this to

You will likely also need to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's a somewhat related post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200912/2108024

Comment: Thanks, mentioned before that i can not use BindIn as i need to put all params in one bean. So will have to use BindBean. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to use BindBean in this fashion. I think you're going to need to use BindIn somehow - by getting the list in the java layer, or having MyFilter implement iterable (which would allow you to use it in BindIn)